# How can I create a temporary file for writing in C++ on a Linux platform?

Tags: c++, linux, temporary-files

In C++, on Linux, how can I write a function to return a temporary filename that I can then open for writing?

The filename should be as unique as possible, so that another process using the same function won't get the same name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use one of the standard library "mktemp" functions: mktemp/mkstemp/mkstemps/mkdtemp.

Edit: plain mktemp can be insecure - mkstemp is preferred.

Comment: these return an already open FILE handle, which doesn't mix with C++'s IO streams. What if you need, for example, to use std::wofstream in order to write to this new file?

Answer (score 7):

tmpnam(), or anything that gives you a name is going to be vulnerable to race conditions.  Use something designed for this purpose that returns a handle, such as tmpfile():

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   FILE *tmpfile(void);
```

Answer (score 3):

The GNU libc manual discusses the various options available and their caveats:

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Temporary-Files.html

Long story short, only mkstemp() or tmpfile() should be used, as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

man tmpfile

> The tmpfile()  function  opens  a  unique  temporary  file  in  binary
>          read/write (w+b) mode.  The file will be automatically deleted when  it
>          is closed or the program terminates.ote

Answer (score 0):

mktemp should work or else get one of the plenty of available libraries to generate a UUID.

Answer (score 0):

The [tmpnam()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam.html) function in the C standard library is designed to solve just this problem. There's also tmpfile(), which returns an open file handle (and automatically deletes it when you close it).

Comment: Don't use tmpnam(). From the man page:

       "Never use this function.  Use mkstemp(3) or tmpfile(3) instead."

Comment: Oops. I wasn't paying attention to the "on Linux" part of the question. mkstemp() is probably the right solution, if you don't need portability.

Answer (score -2):

You should simply check if the file you're trying to write to already exists.
This is a locking problem.
Files also have owners so if you're doing it right the wrong process will not be able to write to it.